# Why does recaptcha make a GET request automatically in Angular 4 app?

Tags: angular, recaptcha

I'm trying to integrate Google's Recaptcha into my Angular 4 application to defend my login for against brute force attacks. For that, I installed the angular2-recaptcha plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/angular2-recaptcha) and I modified my login form like so:

```
<form #loginForm="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(loginForm.value)">
  <h2>Login</h2>
  <label for="inputEmail">Email</label>
  <input type="email" id="inputEmail" required ngModel name="username">
  <label for="inputPassword">Password</label>
  <input type="password" id="inputPassword" required ngModel name="password">
  <re-captcha *ngIf="tooManyRequests" site_key="[my site key]" (captchaResponse)="handleCorrectCaptcha($event)"></re-captcha>
  <button type="submit">Login</button>
</form>
```

Then in login-component.ts, I have the following method to handle the recaptcha callback:

```
handleCorrectCaptcha(event) {
    this.recaptchaResponse = event;
}
```

And the submit of the login form:

```
onSubmit(user: any) {
    this.authService.authenticateUser(<UserDetail>user, this.recaptchaResponse).subscribe((result) => {
      if (!result) {
          this.invalidCredentials = true;
      }
      this.tooManyRequests = false;
      this.recaptchaResponse = null;
   }, (error) => {
      if (error instanceof TooManyRequestsError) {
        this.tooManyRequests = true;
      } 
   });
 }
```

If I add some breakpoints, I see that when I submit my form after having ticked the box "I am not a robot", onSubmit is correctly called with the right parameters and everything, but then everything is interrupted by a GET request on `login?username=something&password=somethingelse&g-recaptcha-response=token` and I don't know where this request is coming from. I was expecting to be able to send the recaptcha token myself to my API and then validate it on the server side.

Anybody know what I am missing?

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. Sort of. The form didn't have an action or method, and it was not a problem. But with the recaptcha field in it, it seems it bypasses the ngSubmit even handler. I added `onsubmit="return false;"` to the form and now it does not make this GET request anymore.